# How to fix index getting lost when ussing append within a nested for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nested

I want to filter out rows from a dataframe which are below a threshold (5th percentile)in another dataframe

I have tried doing a nested for loop and appending the output but index is lost
and that runtime is really long over two minutes

I have a dataframe called fiveperc which is in the format (366,1):

```
    tmin
1   11.32
2   11.0
3   11.41
4   11.885
5   12.155
....
366 13.08
```

and another dataframe called df2 in the format of (18910,1)

```
date    tmin
1966-01-01  13.9
1966-01-02  17.1
1966-01-03  17.1
1966-01-04  16.2
.....
2018-12-31  17
```

Using:

```
anomaly = []
for yearday,perc in fiveperc.iterrows():
    for date,temp in df2.iterrows():
        if yearday == date.dayofyear:
            anomaly.append(temp - perc)
anomaly = pd.DataFrame(anomaly)
```

Using the first block of code above has an output dataframe (18910,1):

```
index   tmin
0   2.58
1   3.27
2   4.27
3   2.08
4   -3.52
....
18909   5.579
```

The problem here is that datetime index from df2 is lost, resulting in a different arrangement!
and that this nested for loop takes over two minutes to run.

extra code if i get the code above work:

```
anomaly[anomaly>0]=np.nan
anomaly[anomaly<0]= 1 
anomaly.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
Frequency = pd.DataFrame(final.groupby(lambda x: x.dayofyear)['anomaly'].agg(sum))
```

Is there a much better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lookup the dayoftheyear on a column with the dt accessor:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
        date  tmin
0 1966-01-01  13.9
1 1966-01-02  17.1
2 1966-01-03  17.1
3 1966-01-04  16.2

In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
     tmin
1  11.320
2  11.000
3  11.410
4  11.885
5  12.155

In [13]: df1.loc[df.date.dt.dayofyear, "tmin"]
Out[13]:
1    11.320
2    11.000
3    11.410
4    11.885
Name: tmin, dtype: float64

In [14]: df["tmin"] - df1.loc[df.date.dt.dayofyear, "tmin"].values
Out[14]:
0    2.580
1    6.100
2    5.690
3    4.315
Name: tmin, dtype: float64
```

---

You can also do this with a groupby transform, but my suspicion is this will be slightly slower:

```
In [21]: df.groupby(df.date.dt.dayofyear)["tmin"].transform(lambda x: x - df1.loc[x.name, "tmin"])
Out[21]:
0    2.580
1    6.100
2    5.690
3    4.315
Name: tmin, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Your answer is great! Just one more thing because my df2 actually has the datetime as the index rather than in your case df as having the usual index and the datetime object in a separate column. Using your code above gives me an ```AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt' ``` error. Which is fine, because i can just create another copy of my df2 that will have the date as column to eliminate this. But it begs the question; how come i get this error?

Comment: @WarenDaleSoriano you can do `df.index.dayofyear`, because it's a datetimeindex it doesn't need the .dt